# Clone a Linux partition to a new SSD and keep both partitions in GRUB

Tags: linux, partition, grub, disk, clonezilla

I have the following disks and partitions:

```
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 174,5G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   529M  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0  63,5G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                 /
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0 467,7G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 416,8G  0 part /mnt/storage
└─sdb5   8:21   0  46,8G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 476,9G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`sda` is an SSD containing a Windows partition (`sda2`) and an Ubuntu partition I'm currently using (`sda4`). `sdb` is an HDD used mainly for storage. `sdc` is a new SSD.

I want to clone `sda4` to `sdc` and keep entries for both `sda4` and the new cloned partition in GRUB. This is what I'm thinking of at the moment:

1. Use GParted to create an `ext4` partition `sdc1` on `sdc`.
2. Boot Clonezilla from a flash drive.
3. Clone `sda4` to `sdc1`.
4. Boot Ubuntu from a flash drive.
5. Generate a new UUID for `sdc1` using GParted or command line.
6. Mount `sdc1` and update its `/etc/fstab` file with the new UUID.
7. Run `sudo update-grub`.

I have doubts about the last point. Can it be done on a live Ubuntu? But if I reboot beforehand, I won't know which partition is present in GRUB - `sda4` or `sdc1` (and does it really matter?)?

Is there an easier way to do all of that?

Comment: I always suggest new install & restore from your backup. Also verifies that your backup is complete while you still have the old install to get any missing info. UEFI or BIOS installs. MBR or gpt drives. I like to use Boot-Repair's report just to document my system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Duplicate UUID can lead to one partition getting updated one time & other next time without first set of updates, or major issue. Min Desktop backup should be /home & list of installed apps. Maybe some settings in /etc or anything else manually changed in / settings, like grub settings.

Comment: GParted will allow you ro copy partitions using the GUI.  Click `sda4`, then right click, choose copy, then right click `sdc`as a whole, and choose paste.  No reason to clone at all as long as `sdc` contains free space.  You can't copy a partition into an existing one.